# 17.10 minimum print screen - no more popup window just screenshot in Pictures

Tags: gnome, 17.10, clipboard, screenshot

Since I upgrade to 17.10 when I do PrtScr or Ctl+Sht+PrtScr it just get the screen shot in the Pictures directory. Before I had a popup window with different options (naming, pasting into clipbboard, etc).

Is there a way to have this popup back ?